# Making cardboard video view by textureview's video in android

Tags: android, google-cardboard, textureview

I'm trying to make cardboard view(stereoscopic view) on my android app
Currently I can show a live video using textureview but I don't know how to combine this with cardboardview.

As my understanding, when show the video in cardboardview I need to use Surfacetexture so I simply initialize that and use getsurfacetexture() in textureview methods but It doesn't work Is there anyone can give me an advice?

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you already found a solution? I want to show a static video (no 360° video) in stereoscopic view.

Comment: @DenisLoh Yes I  solved it a while ago.. Basically you need to make a texture from the video and render it with shader. I uploaded an Android [GoogleVR camera preview example](https://github.com/kjw0723/GoogleVR-CameraExample). You can check this out